# Native ESP32 MQTT library Secure connection error

Tags: ssl, mqtt, esp32, mbedtls, hivemq

**Hello everyone.**

I want to setup an MQTT client on my esp. I was able to do it without SSL, and it is working fine with cloud mqtt providers if it is not secure. I used it with https://www.emqx.com/en/cloud and it was good. Now i want to implement secure connection feature.

For this, i pick https://www.hivemq.com because it is free and allows secure connections. I got a CA from the server with openssl on windows with the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <IDHERE>accountID</IDHERE>.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883
```

**If i generate a PEM CA with keytool like this:**

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore hivemq.jks -alias hivemq -keypass <PWHERE> -storepass <PWHERE>-rfc -file hivemq-server-cert.pem
```

**I got the exact same error from the ESP**

The CA looks fine for me. ( I also tried with other CAs like one of my own CA from https://zerossl.com but it obviously did not work since the dns does not match )

I got the following error on the ESP32 side on the Serial.

```
E (25952) esp-tls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x2700
E (25956) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (25956) TRANS_SSL: Failed to open a new connection
E (25957) MQTT_CLIENT: Error transport connect
```

It seems to me that the CA is not okay.
**Here is my sketch:**

```
const char* mqttServer = "mqtts://<IDHERE>accountID</IDHERE>.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud";
const char* mqtt_user = "test";
const char* mqtt_pwd = "test1234567";

esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg;
esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqtt_client;

const char* pemFile = R"literal(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----)literal";

inline esp_err_t mqttEvent(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event) {
    esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqttclient = event->client;
    switch (event->event_id) {
        case MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED:
            onMqttConnect(mqttclient);
            break;
        case MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
            mqttConnected = false;
            break;
        case MQTT_EVENT_DATA:
            onMqttData(event);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ESP_OK;
}

const size_t mqttJsonSize = 15000;
String mqttBuffer;
static const inline void setupMQTT(){
    mqttBuffer.reserve(mqttJsonSize);
    Serial.print("mqtt_setup: "); Serial.println(mqttServer);
    mqtt_cfg.event_handle   =   mqttEvent;
    mqtt_cfg.uri            =   mqttServer;
    //mqtt_cfg.port           =   15902; // this port is working fine with non ssl connection
    mqtt_cfg.port           =   8883; // current mqtts port.
    
    //mqtt_cfg.task_stack     =   10048; // it was just a test
    mqtt_cfg.username=(const char *)mqtt_user;
    mqtt_cfg.password=(const char *)mqtt_pwd;
    //mqtt_cfg.use_secure_element = true;  // not supported error?

    mqtt_cfg.cert_pem       =   (const char *)pemFile;
    //mqtt_cfg.client_key_pem =   (const char *)keyPemFile; // it was a test. i did not get a key with the openssl command.

    mqtt_client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqtt_cfg);
    if( esp_mqtt_client_start(mqtt_client) == ESP_OK){
        Serial.println("MQTT init success.");  // this line prints with or without TLS
    }else{
        Serial.println("Problem on mqtt INIT");
    }
}


void onMqttConnect(esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client) {
    mqttConnected = true;
    esp_mqtt_client_subscribe(client, receiveTopic, 0);
    Serial.print("subscribed to: "); Serial.println(receiveTopic);
}


void onMqttData(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event) {
    // working with non SSL
    boolean packageOk = false;
    mqttBuffer += String(event->data).substring(0, event->data_len);
    if(mqttBuffer.length() >= event->total_data_len){packageOk = true;}

    if(packageOk){
     // packet is ok to process.    
    }
}
```

**open ssl command response in CMD:**

```
CONNECTED(000001A4)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<HERE IS THE CA></HERE IS THE CA>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = *.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4520 bytes and written 446 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: <sessionid>
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: <masterkey>
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1633589568
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
closed
```

**MY current heap consumption with TLS:**

1. TOTAL_SKETCH --> 3.13 MB
2. USED_SKETCH  --> 1.47 MB
3. TOTAL_HEAP   --> 303.21 KB
4. FREE_HEAP    --> 104.5 KB
5. TOTAL_PSRAM  --> 4 MB
6. FREE_PSRAM   --> 3.89 MB
7. USED_PSRAM   --> 109.47 KB
8. TOTAL_FS     --> 9.69 MB
9. USED_FS      --> 780 KB
10. FREE_FS     --> 8.93 MB

I'm using an *ESP32-WROVER-E* bare chip with 16mb FLASH and 4mb external RAM.

Also i'm not using WiFi, instead of a *LAN8720 Ethernet Chip* with the built in ETH library.
( every http or https request is working fine to my server with the zerossl CA and it is also running an Async webserver which is working fine too )

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: Why not use https://test.mosquitto.org, which has a CA cert for its port 8883 and 8884 available for download, and you can try and make sure your code works.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, with test.mosquitto.org on port 8883 with their CA it is working fine.